# Cannot install network-2.4.0.1 with cabal-install 1.11.0

Tags: networking, haskell, cabal, cabal-install, build-dependencies

I can't install a bunch of different things with `cabal` because they depend on `network-2.4.0.1` which fails to install with:

```
Preprocessing library network-2.4.0.1...
Socket.hsc: In function ‘main’:
Socket.hsc:1054: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1054: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1054: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1060: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
Socket.hsc:1061: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
Socket.hsc:1062: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
compiling dist/build/Network/Socket_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
```

Any clues on how to proceed? (Am using Haskell Platform 2012.2.0.0 on Ubuntu 10.04).

Some googling revealed this is an issue with `cabal-install-1.11` but attempts to update that
are stymied by the dependency on ... `network-2.4.0.1` !

Per @Yuras@ suggestion, here's the output of `cabal -v install network` near the `configure` section:

```
checking for struct msghdr.msg_control... yes
checking for struct msghdr.msg_accrights... no
checking for struct sockaddr.sa_len... no
checking for in_addr_t in netinet/in.h... yes
checking for SO_PEERCRED and struct ucred in sys/socket.h... yes
checking for _head_libws2_32_a in -lws2_32... no
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for gai_strerror... yes
checking whether AI_ADDRCONFIG is declared... yes
checking whether AI_ALL is declared... yes
checking whether AI_NUMERICSERV is declared... yes
checking whether AI_V4MAPPED is declared... yes
checking whether IPV6_V6ONLY is declared... yes
checking for sendfile in sys/sendfile.h... yes 
checking for sendfile in sys/socket.h... no
checking for gethostent... yes
checking for accept4... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
```

Here's more information from the `config.log`. First the `Output Variables`

```
CFLAGS='-D_GNU_SOURCE -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads'
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS='-D_GNU_SOURCE'
```

and here's the bit about `PEERCRED`

```
configure:4301: checking for SO_PEERCRED and struct ucred in sys/socket.h
configure:4329: gcc -c -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:39: error: storage size of 'u' isn't known
configure:4335: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Haskell network package"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "network"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.3.0.14"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Haskell network package 2.3.0.14"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "libraries@haskell.org"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_FCNTL_H 1
| #define HAVE_LIMITS_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_ARPA_INET_H 1
| #define HAVE_NETDB_H 1
| #define HAVE_NETINET_IN_H 1
| #define HAVE_NETINET_TCP_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_UIO_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_UN_H 1
| #define HAVE_READLINK 1
| #define HAVE_SYMLINK 1
| #define HAVE_STRUCT_MSGHDR_MSG_CONTROL 1
| #define HAVE_IN_ADDR_T 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <sys/types.h>
| #include <sys/socket.h>
| #ifndef SO_PEERCRED
| # error no SO_PEERCRED
| #endif
| struct ucred u;
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4378: gcc -c -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wl,--hash-size=31 -Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads  conftest.c >&5
configure:4384: $? = 0
configure:4414: result: yes
```

Thanks!,

Ranjit.

Comment: please run `cabal` in verbose mode (-v) and show `configure` output. The most interesting part is near `for SO_PEERCRED and struct ucred in sys/socket.h`

Comment: Just added that above. Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: ok, ty. Please paste part of config.log between `checking for SO_PEERCRED and struct ucred in sys/socket.h` and the next `result: yes`. Also at the end of config.log the is a section "Output variables.". Please paste `CFLAGS` and `EXTRA_CPPFLAGS` values

Comment: hmm. Can you tell me where the `config.log` is written? Thanks!

Comment: try `cabal unpack network`, `cd` into the package dir and run `cabal configure -v`. `config.log` will appear in the package dir

Comment: Can you try `cabal install cabal-install-0.14.0 --constraint="network < 2.4" --dry-run`? If it's a problem with your version of cabal-install (you wrote 1.11, but it's still at 0.*, so is it 0.11?) not being able to cope with network-2.4.*, first installing a newer version using `network < 2.4` may solve it.

Comment: Looks like a bug in cabal -- it doesn't pass `-D_GNU_SOURCE` to hsc2hs. Try `cabal build -v` and check cmd args passed to hsc2hs. They should contain "--cflag=-D_GNU_SOURCE". If not -- then it is cabal bug

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/859), looks like it is you case. It is marked fixed.

Comment: I saw that ticket, and so was trying to reinstall `cabal` which led back to the circularity. Am trying @Daniel Fischer's suggestion now, but may have to reinstall HP-2012...